# Updating Master Subscriber DE from Triggered Send DEs

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

​We want to ​​allow subscribers immediate access to preference management by assigning the Subscriber Key at the point of email entry (on our website) rather than ​through our 3rd party vendor, which causes a ​two-day ​delay. ​Our Dev team has determined that they can do this with the MD5 hash, which is what the 3rd party vendor uses.

The problem we are running into is trying to figure out whether data extension data in​ our ​Transactional​ Business​ Unit from triggered sends can be exported to​ the ​M​aster ​S​ubscriber ​T​able​ in our Enterprise​ Business Unit. We want to feed these new entries to the Master Subscriber Table so it is up-to-date and relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you could achieve this.
1. You can create a query activity which reads from the DE in the transactional business unit and add/update the Master subscriber DE in ENT Business unit. 
2. You can write up an ampscript on the triggered send email whihc updates the Master DE on the email send.

Hope this helps